# Windows Server 2012 Can't Delete Folder/Files

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012, command-line-interface

I've got a folder with two ISO files in it and I don't need them anymore, however I can't delete the folder! I am an administrator and also the owner of the files.

When I try and delete using windows explorer the files disappear, but as soon as I refresh they return!

When I try and delete with command prompt and arguments /F and /Q I get access is denied.

Any ideas?!

Comment: What is the path of the folder?  Did you use an elevated command prompt?

Comment: D:\Operating Systems\Windows\Windows Server\Windows Server 2012 R2 x64.iso and D:\Operating Systems\Windows\Windows Server\Windows Server 2012 R2 x64.iso. Yes I ran it as admin

Comment: Is your Windows Server 2012 Running Hyper-V ? My though is, maybe *.iso are mounted on some VM template or something.

Comment: Have you tried shift+delete?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like said previously, your files may be in use. 
You can see who use which files on your server by getting in the "managament console".

To do so, right click on the "computer" icon and then click on something like "manage" (I use French OS so I may be wrong in the translation).

Once here you must go in "Shared Files" and then "Opened Files"

Plus, be sure that your .iso files aren't mounted on your server or client.
I hope this will soluce your problem.

EDIT1 : Is your Windows Server 2012 running Hyper-V ? Maybe a VM or template use your *.iso

Comment: According to Windows there are currently no open files.

Comment: It is running hyper-v but we only used the ISOs to create new Virtual machines, not run off them and they are not mounted.

Comment: Turns out the ISO files were mounted on a different server for some reason. Unmounted, the files disappeared right away!

Comment: Good to know, have a good day.

Comment: Having this issue... except there is nothing listed under Shared, Sessions, or Open Files

Answer (score 1):

If 'Opened Files' doesn't show anything then it will be an internal process locking the file.

I found that restarting a 3rd party archiving service did the trick. (Even though the software wasn't supposed to be working on those file any more).

Comment: This was the answer. For me it was a Git GUI that was doing something with an empty folder...

Answer (score -2):

There are 2 reasons i can guess  :

1. Maybe your files are in use, close all open applications and try again.
2. Windows explorer or command window is not running as administrator. Simply right click on `.exe` file and click "Run as administrator".

Comment: There are no applications running. I was running as administrator.

Comment: Where is exact location of your file? (Give me full address)

Comment: Also, please check your event viewer for related errors on windows explorer

Comment: D:\Operating Systems\Windows\Windows Server\Windows Server 2012 R2 x64.iso and D:\Operating Systems\Windows\Windows Server\Windows Server 2012 R2 x64.iso.
Already checked event viewer. No errors.

Comment: Unfortunately due to the nature of our business I cannot let you into our servers.